# Relation between master page and non master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

There is a  page Login.aspx having a Label control as  "Lbl_LoginExpired".
There is also a MasterPage.
I want to change the text of "Lbl_LoginExpired" from within the Master Page.
How can i achieve this?

> Note: 
>   1) Login.aspx is NOT a Content page.
>
> 2) `Label label1=new (Label)Login.FndControl("Lbl_LoginExpired")`
>         is NOT working in MasterPage.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: I am targeting Asp.net

Comment: I know as is is clear from the question. But we need it in a Tag so it is also clear from the Questions overview page!

Answer (score 1):

If there is no master page- content relationship between these 2 pages. I think your options are limited. Also i am assuming Lbl_LoginExpired is not a part of an user control that you can register in both pages. I would recommend using Session object to pass this information between these 2 pages.

Hence in your master page

```
 Session["expiredtext"] = "Your login has been expired";
```

And in your login pag check this session value whether it is null or not and show the content of it.

```
Lbl_LoginExpired.Text=Session["expiredtext"]?.ToString();
```

Also do not forget to reset (or abonden session when user logs out)

Comment: Gonzales Gokhan thank you for your help, i was wondering about the reset part too, and u provided the lead for  it. :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark as an answer to inform  community that it solves the issue